# Two form groups, two tabs in last group

Tags: sonata-admin

Here is my code:

```
    $formMapper
        ->with('Order', [
            'class' => 'col-md-6'
        ])
        ->add('customer')
        ->end()
        ->with('Activity', [
            'class' => 'col-md-6'
        ])
        ->add('poNumber')
        ->end()->end()
        ->tab('Test')
```

How do I keep the two groups - but the second group needs two or more tabs?

EDIT | The above is adding two tabs "Default" and "Test" with "Default" showing the two groups...

Comment: You cannot with native comportment. The 'with' are children of 'tab', not inverse..

Comment: Is there an alternative component which I might use to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know, but if you really want this, you can override the edit layout, and render your fields one by one where you want.

Comment: Meh...I was really just experimenting with SA so I could learn how it differed from just using SSE CRUD generators. Some neat benefits, but I wanted to see how far I could go before I had to start fighting the thing. I guess I've reached that point :p